# Фоновая задача. Android

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Необходимо выполнять какую-либо задачу в фоновом режиме, но даже если приложение закрыто. К примеру приложение отправляет запрос на сервер, сервер что-то возвращает и приложение пишет эти данные в бд. Возможно ли это? Я знаю, что сервисы живут даже в том случае, если приложение свернуто, но как только приложение закрывают - сервис умирает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего происходит Unbinding и сервис завершает работу. Попробуйте запускать сервис через метод startService.

Comment: Разобрался! Спасибо.